# Making AJAX JSON request to PHP file (parse error)

Tags: php, json, ajax

I have a PHP file in which I'm getting data from a geoJSON file, I'm going through the data and storing what I need in a new associative array, then sorting it. I need to make an AJAX call to this PHP file to get the sorted data through, but it's throwing "SyntaxError: Unexpected token a in JSON at position 0", the "a" being "a"rray... from the response, so I believe it's going through as a string.

My PHP file:

```
<?php

$countryBordersJson = file_get_contents("../js/countryBorders.geojson");
$countryBordersJsonData = json_decode($countryBordersJson, true);

$dataLength = count($countryBordersJsonData['features']);
$countryNames = array();

for($i = 0; $i < $dataLength; $i++) {
    $countryName = $countryBordersJsonData['features'][$i]['properties']['name'];
    $countryIsoa2 = $countryBordersJsonData['features'][$i]['properties']['iso_a2'];

    $country[$i]['countryName'] = $countryName;
    $country[$i]['iso_a2'] = $countryIsoa2;

    array_push($countryNames, $country[$i]);
}

sort($countryNames);
$data = json_encode($countryNames);

$decode = json_decode($data, true);

$output['status']['code'] = "200";
$output['status']['name'] = "ok";
$output['status']['description'] = "success";
$output['data'] = $decode;

header('Content-Type: application/json');

var_dump($output);

?>
```

My AJAX request:

```
$.ajax({
      url: "libs/php/countryBorders.php",
      dataType: "json",
      type: "GET",
      success: function(result) {
        console.log(result);
      },
      error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.warn(jqXHR.responseText, textStatus, errorThrown);
      }
    })
```

I'm still getting to grips with JSON, PHP etc. so would appreciate any help.

Comment: Open up your browser's developer console and see what response you're getting back from the PHP file. It looks like you're getting HTML back instead of json. However, you should echo a json string, `var_dump` will not be a valid format.

Comment: Thanks! I json_encoded the $output variable and echo'd it and that worked. Previously when I was trying to json_encode I was var_dumping it, and it was returning the data all as 1 string. I thought that trying to eho it would throw a TypeError. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sending the data with var_dump ? It cannot work like that. You need to send a string :

```
echo json_encode($output);
```